# Como extrair palavras separadas por espaço via Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, loop

Continuando a maratona de artigos referente a extração de textos, reparei que este tipo de pergunta é muito difícil de ser encontrada junto à uma resposta clara e direta.

Afim de tirar a minha dúvida e certamente a de outros usuários, **o problema de hoje é o seguinte:**

Imagine que foi declarado uma var do tipo string de valor:

```
var texto = "Eu quero tirar minhas duvidas sobre Javascript"
```

Em uma situação, por exemplo, onde deve-se buscar **itens** filtrando pelo seu nome em uma determinada lista com itens de nome **X**, ao invés de retornar um valor *undefined* quando o texto digitado no campo não for compatível com o nome de nenhum item na lista devido a busca ser **exata**, há como criar um loop (*for* por exemplo) onde ele irá pegar palavra por palavra (separada pelo espaço na string) pada poder, assim, fazer uma busca mais dinâmica dentro dessa lista?

Comment: Coloquei métodos para "partir a frase em pedaços". Onde vais usar isto? é numa função de busca tipo google que queres usar cada palavra para fazer um match?

Comment: Só que eu quero mais uma condição no match. O length das palavras tem que ser maior que 1

Comment: Como faço isso?

Comment: Se a parte que te faltava era somente o que respondi podes marcar a resposta como aceite se quiseres. Se não mostra mais código que posso ajudar a completar.

Comment: É esta condição que eu quero agora. Não quero que ele extraia palavras como tamanhos menores que 2

Comment: Nesse caso podes filtrar os resultados tipo `palavras = palavras.filter(str => str.length > 2);`

Comment: Respondendo sua pergunta: Sim! Eu quero usar cada palavra para fazer um match e retornar um valor específico.

Comment: Faz um jsFiddle com o que tens que fica fácil de corrigir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando RegExp:

```js
var texto = "Eu quero tirar minhas duvidas sobre Javascript";
var palavras = texto.match(/[^\s]+/g);
console.log(palavras);
```

Usando `.split()`:

```js
var texto = "Eu quero tirar minhas duvidas sobre Javascript";
var palavras = texto.split(' ');
console.log(palavras);
```

Comment: Obrigado! Fico feliz pela atenção ao problema. Imagino que isto irá ajudar a mim e muitos outros usuários!

Comment: Agora posso usar o for para fazer uma busca de palavra por palavra! :D